# How to get methods from class that implements interface dynamically?

Tags: java, reflection

I'm working on a simple 2D game in Java. There's 2 Robot: they can move, fight etc.. These classes implement same interface.

**Questions are**:

1. How to instantiate Robots in run time? I mean, when the program is running, ask the user to load classes, after that use their methods (Press 1 to get your own shield points..) like a role playing games.. I tried to do with Reflection but it doesn't work on interface.

   *My reflection method:*

   ```
   public void invokeClassMethod(String classBinaryName, String methodName) {

       try {
           ClassLoader classLoader = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
           Class<?> loadClass = classLoader.loadClass(classBinaryName);

           System.out.println("Loaded class name: " + loadClass.getName());

           Constructor<?> constructor = loadClass.getConstructor();
           Object classObject = constructor.newInstance();

           Method method = loadClass.getMethod(methodName);
           System.out.println("Invoked method name: " + method.getName());
           method.invoke(classObject);

       } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
       } catch (Exception ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
       }
   }
   ```
2. Is it a good way to get ***enemyPosition***()?

*Robot interface:*

```
public interface Robot {

    public String getPosition();

    public String getEnemyPosition();

    public String getArenaSize();

    public int getShield();

}
```

*Robot1 class:*

```
public class Robot1 implements Robot {

    private int xCurrent;
    private int yCurrent;
    private int shield;
    private final int attack = 1;

    Robot robot2;

    public Robot1() {
    }

    public Robot1(int x, int y, int shield, Robot robot2) {
        this.xCurrent = x;
        this.yCurrent = y;
        this.shield = shield;
        this.robot2 = robot2;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPosition() {
        return "x: " + xCurrent + " y: " + yCurrent;
    }

    @Override
    public String getEnemyPosition() {
        return robot.getPosition();
    }

    @Override
    public int getShield() {
        return shield;
    }
}
```

3. Furthermore the Arena class stores game board informations like arena size, printing etc... If I want to operate on this arena (moving Robot objects [1][1] ---> [3][2]) how to connect Robot interface and Arena with each other?
4. Where to store their positions (in concrete class or somewhere else)? Is aggregation a best way?How to avoid tight coupling?

Comment: You cannot instantiate an interface in Java, directly and your Robot is an interface you should use your implementation Robot1 class.

Comment: I know that, my questions focus on reflection.

Comment: Your question does not focus on reflection, your question is "How to instantiate dynamically interface ?" the answer is you can't instantiate an interface. Then your question is too broad for this site since you are asking multiple question at once. Please have a look to [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: If you did correctly load the implementation class, it’s not clear which problems you have invoking the interface methods. It should work both ways, directly by casting to the interface type or via Reflection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Like this

```
public Robot loadByClassName(String classname) {
    Class<?> loadClass;
    try {
        loadClass = Class.forName(classname);
        return (Robot) loadClass.getConstructor().newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;

}
```

2. Not really, maybe you could create a class Position with x and y properties
3. I think arena object should hold the objects which are in the arena (your robots)
4. A Map in the arena with key Position (see 2.) and value Robot would be my approach

Comment: Note that `this.getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass(classname)` is obsolete most of the time as you can simply use `Class.forName(classname)` which uses the caller’s class loader. Differences could only arise if there could be subclasses of your class loaded by a different class loader.